# Information on Windows 7 RDP limitations needed

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

We are going to use Windows 7 and have couple of users to work remotely in Windows 7.

Please can you tell me, what kind of limitations does it have?

1. Number of concurrent users that can work in Windows 7 remotely via RDP.
2. Is there any other limitations?
3. Does it depend on Windows 7 flavors? (Pro, Ultimate etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-server versions of Windows are not multi-user, meaning that only one user can be logged in at a time, total. This means one user at the console or one user logged in via RDP.

In order to have multiple users connected, you will need to invest in an edition of Windows Server that provides Remote Desktop Service, which means purchasing Windows Server and then additionally purchasing Client Access Licenses for the number of simultaneous users you need to support.

Note that Windows 7 Home Premium does not provide an RDP server at all, only Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate have an RDP server available (and of course it is single-user).

**UPDATE** (added by question author)

Windows 7 have 20 concurrent connections limitation, it means network connections (e.g to single SMB share). But when it comes RDP - read above.

Comment: Pretty much sums it up. . .